# How to obtain address of trait object?

Tags: rust

How do you obtain address of trait object? I tried this:

```rust
fn func() {}

fn main() {
    let boxed_func: Box<dyn Fn()> = Box::new(func);

    println!("expect: {:p}", func as *const ()); // 0x55bb0207e570

    println!("actual: {:p}", &boxed_func); // 0x7ffe5217e5a0
    println!("actual: {:p}", Box::into_raw(boxed_func)); // 0x1
}
```

But it yields different addresses.

Comment: The second line gives the address of the `Box`, not of its content. I'm not sure about the third line, however: looks like it has simply failed, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the easy one: as mentioned in the comments, `&boxed_func` is simply the address of the local variable `boxed_func`, not the address of the underlying data. Think of it as a pointer to the pointer.

Now the hard part. I think one thing that's confusing you is that pointers to trait objects are *fat pointers*, and this isn't reflected by printing with `"{:p}"`. They consist of a pointer to the actual data as well as a pointer to a vtable, which stores information about the implementation of the trait.

This can be seen with the (likely UB) code

```rust
fn func() {}

fn main() {
    let boxed_func: Box<dyn Fn()> = Box::new(func);

    println!("function pointer: {:p}", func as fn()); // 0x560ae655d1a0
    println!("trait object data pointer: {:p}", boxed_func); // 0x1
    println!("stack pointer: {:p}", &boxed_func); // 0x7ffebe8f4688

    let raw = Box::into_raw(boxed_func);
    println!("raw data pointer: {:p}", raw); // 0x1

    // This is likely undefined behavior, since I believe the layout of trait objects isn't specified
    let more_raw = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, (usize, usize)>(raw) };
    println!("full fat pointer: {:#x}, {:#x}", more_raw.0, more_raw.1); // 0x1, 0x560ae6789468
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1af08cc56359a3215fb94f4be2a8feec)

So the actual underlying pointer of `boxed_func` consists of two pointers: `0x1` and `0x55ec289004c8` (results may vary here). `0x1` is the usual value for pointers to zero-sized types. Obviously, you don't want to use a null pointer for this purpose, but you don't really need a valid pointer, either. Zero-sized types are often allocated using [`Unique::empty`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.42.0/src/core/ptr/unique.rs.html#76), which simply returns a dangling pointer to the memory location at the alignment of the type (the alignment of a zero-sized type is 1).

```rust
// Some zero-sized types and where they get allocated

struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(());
    println!("{:p}", x); // 0x1

    let y = Box::new(Foo);
    println!("{:p}", y); // 0x1
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8978595dc4efb519d4b876d2b82dd047)

So in our situation with the trait object, this is telling us that the data part of the trait object is (probably) a zero-sized type, which makes sense since `func` doesn't have any data associated to it other than what's needed to call it. That information is kept in the `vtable`.

---

A safer (less UB inducing) way to see the raw parts of the trait object is with the nightly-only struct `TraitObject`.

```rust
#![feature(raw)]
use std::raw::TraitObject;

fn func() {}

fn main() {
    let boxed_func: Box<dyn Fn()> = Box::new(func);

    println!("function: {:p}", func as fn()); // 0x56334996e850
    println!("function trait object: {:p}", boxed_func); // 0x1
    println!("stack address: {:p}", &boxed_func); // 0x7ffee04c2378

    // Safety: `Box<dyn Trait>` is guaranteed to have the same layout as `TraitObject`.
    let trait_object = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, TraitObject>(boxed_func) };
    println!("data pointer: {:p}", trait_object.data); // 0x1
    println!("vtable pointer: {:p}", trait_object.vtable); // 0x563349ba3068
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62992fe2f50e8c33291a53c3331b230c)

Try this out with some other trait objects and see if you can find some that don't have zero-sized data.

---

`TraitObject` is deprecated and according to [Tracking Issue for pointer metadata APIs #81513](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81513), it’s replaced with [`to_raw_parts(self)` method of primitive type pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.to_raw_parts).

```rust
#![feature(ptr_metadata)]

trait Trait {
    fn f(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Struct {
    i: i32
}

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn f(&self) -> i32 {
        self.i
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Struct { i: 1 };
    let sp = &s as *const _;
   
    let (sdynp, sdynvtable) = (&s as &dyn Trait as *const dyn Trait).to_raw_parts();
    
    println!("sp = {:p}", sp);
    
    println!("sdynp = {:p}, sdynvtable = {:#?}", sdynp, sdynvtable);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2573fda08e0d44c24963c7fff340c94)

Comment: "the only thing that matters for dyn Fn() is what the function does" - this is the case here, because function in question is, well, function. It would not be the case with closures, however.

Comment: "It would not be the case with closures, however." [indeed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=07f23e4f3657dad0ee04244e8384b16e) though one should take care not to confuse "anonymous function" and "closure".

Comment: It seems that `TraitObject` is deprecated and according to [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81513), it’s replaced with [`to_raw_parts(self)` method of primitive type pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.to_raw_parts).