# How to simply cast &dyn traits to usize?

Tags: rust

Is there a better way than the following?

```rust
    let a: Arc<dyn Send + Sync> = Arc::new(true);

    println!(
        "{}",
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, (usize, usize)>(a.as_ref()) }.0,
    );
```

Comment: What's the overall goal? Without knowing more it looks answered by: [How to obtain address of trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61378906) which basically has what you have.

Answer (score 1):

If currently unstable Rust features are an option, then `#![feature(ptr_metadata)]` allows you to do this conversion without any `unsafe` by using [`pointer::to_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.to_raw_parts).

```rust
#![feature(ptr_metadata)]

use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let a: Arc<dyn Send + Sync> = Arc::new(true);
    
    let a_ptr: *const (dyn Send + Sync) = a.as_ref();
    let data_ptr_only: *const () = a_ptr.to_raw_parts().0;

    println!("{:p} {}", data_ptr_only, data_ptr_only as usize);
}
```